# Find the length of the longest increasing subsequence using only one auxiliary recursion function

Tags: c, recursion

I need to find the length of the longest monotonically increasing subsequence using only a single recursion function.
For example given an `arr={45 1 21 3 33 6 53 9 18}` it need to give back 5. I have started to write the code but i'm stuck, and i don't know how to find out which of the calls gives the maximum length.

The function `longestSet` is my auxiliary function i can use any variables i want but it have to be called from the function `max_set`.

```
void question3(int question)
{
    int *arr, size;
    printf("enter the array size\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    arr=(int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    fillArr(arr, size-1);
    max_set(arr, size);
    free(arr);
}

void max_set(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i=0, finelmax=0, count=0,longrising;
    longrising=longestSet(arr,size,i,finelmax,count);
    printf("the length of the longest risind set is: %d", longrising);
}

int longestSet(int arr[], int size, int i, int finelmax, int count)
{
    if(i==size)
        return count;

    if(arr[i]>=finelmax)
    {
        finelmax=arr[i];
        return longestSet(arr,size,i+1,finelmax,count+1);
    }

    return longestSet(arr,size,i+1,finelmax,count);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The term "set" is very misleading, since a set is by definition unordered and can't be rising. "Sequence" is more appropriate, I'll edit it in. Additionally, is this homework? It is customary to mark homework with the `homework` tag.

Comment: I don't see any C++ code in here, so I'll mark this as a C question. If both languages are fine with you, add the C++ tag again, next to the C tag.

Comment: No, don't add both the C and C++ tags. They're very different languages, and they imply very different answers. Pick one and stick with it.

Comment: This problem can be reduced to finding the longest sequence of '1's in a binary string.  Perhaps that might help?? - or maybe not - the example doesn't match the problem description as I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
int longestSet(int arr[], int size, int i, int finelmax, int count)
{
    if(i==size) return count;

    int length1 = longestSet(arr, size, i + 1, finelmax, count);
    if(arr[i] > finelmax)
    {
        int length2 = longestSet(arr, size, i + 1, arr[i], count + 1);
        if(length2 > length1) length1 = length2;
    }

    return length1;
}
```

What this basically does is at each point compare if it would be better to include the current number or skip it. Also will be pretty slow - you can for example add memoization to it to improve, but I'm guessing that's not part of the homework?

Comment: First thank you! It's not past of the homework but I'd like to understand what do you mean memoization? Limit the size of the array?

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization - basically it means saving the result of a function somewhere and then using that result instead of computing again if the function is called with the same arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving here the full code with a single recursion function you asked. Unfortunately it's in java but your purpose would be solved as the function used for recursion is almost same.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class longestSubSequence{
    public static void main (String [] args)throws IOException{
    new longestSubSequence().run();
    }

    int max = -1;
    int index = 1;
    int [] array;
    private void run() throws IOException{
    array = new int [50];
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    // Input your array
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (br.readLine());
    array[0] = -1;
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
            array[index++] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    }
    index--;
    dfs (0, 0);
    System.out.println(max);//      Prints the maximum length
    }

    private void dfs (int curr, int length){
        if (length > max )max = length;
        if (curr >= index)
            return ;
        for (int I=curr+1;I <= index; I++){
            if (array[I] >= array[curr]){
                dfs (I, length+1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```