# Find the length of the longest increasing subsequence

Tags: c, sequence

I've written some code in C that, given a sequence, should find the length of the longest increasing subsequence. However it always returns the length 4 when this is incorrect.

Here is my code so far:

```
int LIS(int* seq, int* temp_seq, int seq_size)  
{int i, j;

for(i=0; i<seq_size; i++);
{ 
  temp_seq[i]=0; 
}
  for(i=1; i<seq_size; i++);
  { 
     for(j=1; j<seq_size; j++)
     { 
       if (seq[i]<temp_seq[j])
       seq[i]=temp_seq[j];

       else if (seq[i]>temp_seq[j]) 
       seq[i]=temp_seq[j+1];
     } 
  }
 return(sizeof temp_seq);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also I should note that the sequence lists all integers from 1 to n with no repeated numbers.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8658187/3933332

Comment: Some aspects unclear.  Post sample input and expected output.

Comment: this kind of line: seq[i]=temp_seq[j]; is stepping on the original sequence, probably NOT what you wanted to do.  The only place that temp_seq[] is ever set is in the initial setting of it to all 0

Comment: this line: return(sizeof temp_seq); is returning the size of the pointer temp_seq, which for your C implementation is 4

Comment: the code should allow for discontinuities in the seq list of numbers.  I.E. when a <= new number if encountered, save counter (see above comment) reset counter, clear the temp_seq[] array and continue searching for the longest sequence, as long as the index is < seq_size.

Comment: suggest clearing the temp_seq[] array by: memset( temp_seq, 0x00, seq_size);

Comment: in your code, 'i' should index through the seq[] array, 'j' should index through the temp_seq[] array, with no overlap.  'j' should only be incremented when a new value is to be appended to the temp_seq[] array.  'j' should be reset to 0 whenever a new value is <= to the last saved value

Comment: the 'j' variable would not be a good item to return as it may have been reset after finding a longer array.  Also, *I* would have 2 local areas to work with for extracting the longest sequence, one with the longest sequence found so far and one for building the current sequence.

Comment: these two lines: for(i=1; i<seq_size; i++); have a trailing ';' that terminates the 'for' loop.  I.E. those trailing ';' on the 'for' statements need to be removed.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using a debugger to step through the code, so you can see for your self the many errors in the code.

Comment: This question belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @rubenvb codereview.stackexchange.com is for working code.  OP has "always returns the length 4 ... this is incorrect."

Comment: @chux: right, misread. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

1. Returning wrong value. `return(sizeof temp_seq);` is a constant, the size of the pointer  `temp_seq`.  [@eurythmia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26761710/2410359)
2. The `;` after `for(i=0; i<seq_size; i++);` is certainly not needed as that completes the loop.  Same for `for(i=1; i<seq_size; i++);`.
3. The value of `seq[0]` is never tested nor saved in `temp_seq`.
4. Possible access passed end of array with `seq[i]=temp_seq[j+1];`
5. Code *appears*  to want to clear `temp_seq[]` and then set all `seq[]` with `temp_seq[]`.

Answer (score 0):

`tmp_seq` is declared in the function defintion as a pointer to type `int`. Your function is therefore always returning the size of an `int *` (which happens to be 4 bytes in this case).

Comment: Ah I think I understand that but I'm unsure what to do about it, have you got any tips? Am I going to have to change a lot or am I close?

Comment: Similar to what? As regards to your first suggestion, part of my specification for this program is to have 'int *...' in it so I can't change that.

Comment: there are a few things you can try. The first is to use `int tmp_seq[]` instead of `int *tmp_seq`. The second thing you can try is to keep a counter that you increment whenever you discover that an element is part of an increasing sub-sequence. You will need to keep another counter for the "max size" that you can use to determine if the current sub sequence is larger or smaller than the last.